# AppendData function: Insert JSON Content into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am following [this tutorial](https://howtocreateapps.com/fetch-and-display-json-html-javascript/) to learn how to insert Text from a JSON into an Website. I rebuilt the example on the website succesfully - however I struggle to use my own JSON, which has a slightly different structure.

The JSON from the tutorial looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Mary",
        "lastName": "Peterson"
    },
    ...
]
```

The array is loaded into an object called `data` and I can access each of its values using an index and the key of the value i.e. `data[0].firstName` would result in "John" (as described in the short tutorial).

Now, the JSON I actually want to use has the following structure:

```
{
    "Category1": [
        {
            "name": "Lorem",
            "description": "A description",
            "product": "a product",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "Category2": [
        {
            "name": "Lorem1",
            "description": "Another description",
            "product": "another product",
            ...
        },
        {
            "name": "Lorem2",
            "description": "A third description",
            "product": "a third product"
            ...
        },
        {
            "name": "Lorem3",
            "description": "And one last description",
            "product": "last product",
            ....
        }
    ],
    "Category3": [
        {
        ...
        },
    ],
    ...
}
```

How can I access all of these values? I tried to treat the `data` object as a multidimensional array (i.e. `data[0][1]` without success.

I am using the following function to insert into the HTML:

```
function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].firstName;
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

Also - as a follow-up question: Is there a way to iterate through the Categories at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call by data.ObjectName[index].propertyName

```js
let data = {
  "Category1": [
      {
          "name": "Lorem",
          "description": "A description",
          "product": "a product",
      },
  ]
}

console.log(data.Category1[0].name);
```

For Example:

```js
let data = {
  Category1: [
    {
      name: "Lorem",
      description: "A description",
      product: "a product",
    },
  ],
  Category2: [
    {
      name: "Lorem1",
      description: "Another description",
      product: "another product",
    },
    {
      name: "Lorem2",
      description: "A third description",
      product: "a third product",
    },
  ],
};

for (x in data) {
  for (let i = 0, l = data[x].length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(data[x][i].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, it does not work. I will put my JS code in the question in case it has an error.

Comment: Check the example below .

Answer (score 1):

Well... You can declare your arrays as a "normal" two-dimensional array, like:

```js
const data = [
  [{ "name": "Lorem", "description": "A description", "product": "a product" }],
  [
   { "name": "Lorem1", "description": "A description", "product": "another product" },
   { "name": "Lorem2", "description": "A description", "product": "a third product" }
  ]
];

console.log(data[0][0]);
```

In case when **you can't change your JSON structure** you can iterate using `Object.entiries`:

```js
const data = {
  Category1: [
    {
      name: "Lorem",
      description: "A description",
      product: "a product",
    },
  ],
  Category2: [
    {
      name: "Lorem1",
      description: "Another description",
      product: "another product",
    },
    {
      name: "Lorem2",
      description: "A third description",
      product: "a third product",
    },
  ],
};

Object.entries(data).forEach((entry) => {
  const categoryName = entry[0];
  const values = entry[1];

  // Replace console.logs with your functions that create div's/insert text/etc
  console.log('\n');
  console.log(categoryName);
  values.forEach((value) => {
    console.log('===================');
    console.log(value.name);
    console.log(value.description);
    console.log(value.product);
  });
})
```